# create report in excel by using old data of other sheet

Tags: android, excel

i have data in sheet1 as show below

```
     A           B           C           D          E           F          G
1    C.NO       DATE       STATION      AGENT    NARRATION     CASH       DUE
2    100        01/04/16    KKR         ABC      7145          $1100     $500
3    101        01/04/16    BHL         XYZ      9999          $1500     $100
4    102        02/04/16    RTM         BCD      6792          S1000     $50
```

now i want report in sheet2 as below

```
    A           B           C           D          E           F          G
1    DATE       LD       AMOUNT     NARRATION    TYPE                    C.NO
2    01/04/16   CASH      -$1100      7145        CCC                     100
3               ABC        -$500                  CCC       
4               KKR        $1600                  CCC
5    01/04/16   CASH      -$1500      9999        CCC                     101
6               XYZ        -$100                  CCC
7               BHL        $1600                  CCC
8    02/04/16   CASH      -$1000      6792        CCC                     102
9               BCD         -$50                  CCC
10              RTM        $1050                  CCC
```

in this abc,xyz & bcd are agent who are debtore
        kkr,bhl & rtm are source of income
        cash which collect by this transection
        coloumn "f" is blank 
please give me VBA CODE sheet for this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub transform()

Dim firstrow1, lastrow1 As Integer
Dim lastrow2 As Integer
Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet



    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    With ws2

        .Range("A1").Value = "DATE"
        .Range("B1").Value = "LD"
        .Range("C1").Value = "AMOUNT"
        .Range("D1").Value = "NARRATION"
        .Range("E1").Value = "TYPE"

        .Range("G1").Value = "C.NO"

    End With


    With ws1

        firstrow1 = 2
        lastrow1 = .Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = firstrow1 To lastrow1

            lastrow2 = ws2.Range("B1000000").End(xlUp).Row

            ws2.Range("A" & lastrow2 + 1).Value = .Range("B" & i).Value
            ws2.Range("B" & lastrow2 + 1).Value = "CASH"
            ws2.Range("C" & lastrow2 + 1).Value = "'-" & .Range("F" & i).Value
            ws2.Range("D" & lastrow2 + 1).Value = .Range("E" & i).Value
            ws2.Range("E" & lastrow2 + 1).Value = "CCC"
            ws2.Range("G" & lastrow2 + 1).Value = .Range("A" & i).Value

            ws2.Range("B" & lastrow2 + 2).Value = .Range("D" & i).Value
            ws2.Range("C" & lastrow2 + 2).Value = "'-" & .Range("G" & i).Value
            ws2.Range("E" & lastrow2 + 2).Value = "CCC"

            ws2.Range("B" & lastrow2 + 3).Value = .Range("C" & i).Value
            ws2.Range("C" & lastrow2 + 3).Value = "'$" & Val(Mid(.Range("F" & i).Value, 2, Len(.Range("F" & i).Value) - 1)) + Val(Mid(.Range("G" & i).Value, 2, Len(.Range("G" & i).Value)))
            ws2.Range("E" & lastrow2 + 3).Value = "CCC"

            'lastrow2 = lastrow2 + 3 'alternative
            lastrow2 = ws2.Range("B1000000").End(xlUp).Row

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: If this worked for you, please accept this as the answer.

Comment: it works properly as i want but a little problem is :  in sheet2 coloumn "c" ,row 3 amount is sum of row1 & row2.you vba do something different. iwant sum of row1 & row2 in row3 of coloumn "c".  please solve it .

Comment: For me it is doing just that... The problem is probably how you get your numbers to show in this format: -$####

Comment: I can only help you, if you specify how you get your "-$" format. Do you type it in manually, e.g. like '-$, or do you do it via custom number formatting?

Comment: But then it should work... could you please tell me, what the exact results are that you get in column C? For your info: this is the line in the code that writes into column C:     `ws2.Range("C" & lastrow2 + 3).Value = "'$" & Val(Mid(.Range("F" & i).Value, 2, Len(.Range("F" & i).Value) - 1)) + Val(Mid(.Range("G" & i).Value, 2, Len(.Range("G" & i).Value)))`

Comment: in column "c" in 3rd row its a total of 1st & 2nd row of "c" column.1st & 2nd value of row is in (-) minus but the total of 3rd row is in (+) positive value.it is completely solve my problem.